Not showing the output in Selenium
It tried Selenium to scrap the Indiamart website, but I didn't get any errors. Now I am not getting the output. I don't know where I went wrong.
Here I am copying the code along with output. I want the output in dataframes the data to be extract.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 
import time
import os 
# Set up the service for ChromeDriver
service = Service(r'C:\Users\vamsi\OneDrive\Documents\Selenium\chromedriver.exe')
# Initialize the Chrome WebDriver with the service
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
#URL visit 
driver.get("https://dir.indiamart.com/impcat/boneless-chicken.html")
driver.maximize_window()
#Locate elements using the updated methods
company_names = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//h2[@class="lcname"]')
address = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//p[@class="sm clg"]')
view_mobilenumber = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="mo viewn vmn"]')
contactlist = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="pns-h duet"]')
namelist = []
addresslist = []
numberlist = []
# Calculate the minimum length to avoid index errors
min_length = min(len(names), len(address), len(contactlist))
for i in range(min_length):
    name = comapany_names[i].text
    addresslist = address[i].text
    view_mobilenumber.click()
    contact = contactlist[i].get_attribute("innerHTML")
    
    namelist.append(names)
    addresslist.append(addresslist)
    numberlist.append(contact)
#Intialise data of lists
data = {'company_names': namelist, 'address': addresslist, 'contactlist': numberlist}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
output: - Empty DataFrame
          Columns: [company_names, address, contactlist]
          Index: []
driver.quit()


The main problem is in line 25 where "min_length" is calculated zero (because "len(contactlist)" is equal to zero) and the for loop doesn't even start.
I browsed the website and I realised that in line 20, "contactlist" is not correctly fetched and the dash in the xpath must be replaced with an underline, like this:
contactlist = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="pns_h duet"]')

this will give you the correct output
